# List index out of range error only when run on server - python

Tags: python, discord, feedparser

I hope you can help me with my issue
I am currently coding a bot on discord with python using discord.py

There is a portion of my code which, for the time being, is used to retrieve the latest (or last n) articles from a .xml feed using feedparser.
When I run the code locally from my laptop, the command works just fine with no errors thrown at me.
However, when hosted on the server (ubuntu 18.04), it throws a "list index out of range" error at me each time.

Here is the portion of code in question:

```
i = 0
url = "http://www.aero-news.net/news/rssCOMANW.xml"
feed = feedparser.parse(url)

while i <= 0:
    title = feed.entries[i].title
    link = feed.entries[i].link
    descr = feed.entries[i].description
    i = i + 1

    embed = discord.Embed(title=title, description=f"[Link to the story here]({link})", color=0x272c88)
    embed.add_field(name="Description", value=descr, inline=True)
    embed.set_footer(text="Bug to report? Use !bug <bug description> command!",
                     icon_url="https://crew.sasva.net/lib/images/saswhite.png")

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

I hope you can help me out :) Thank you

Comment: What if `feed.entries` is empty? 

Try to check at first that it has at least one element.

Comment: Thanks @MohammedDeifallah ! That was not apparently the issue, but I checked it nonetheless. Apaprently, the RSS feed I was trying to pull was just rotten and worked half the time. Thanks anyways!